# Portlet customization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have devloped a webpage that has a collection of portlets. Is there any way I can allow a user to customize the portlets (for example resize/remove/change color scheme) and hve the page show the customised layout next time the user logs in, rather than showing up the default layout and styling?

Any hints or an existing example will be appreciated.

```
  <body>
  <div class="demo">
  <div class="header" ><img src="css/images/logo.gif" style="height=100px;width:100px;"/>
  <label class="hd"> Template</label>
   <hr>
  <div class="column" id="col0">
   <div class="portlet" id="p_0">
    <div class="portlet-header">Feeds<a  class="edit" href="#p_0"></a></div>
    <div class="portlet-content">
                Keep Checking this space for latest Feeds
    </div>
            </div>

     <div class="portlet" id="p_1">
     <div class="portlet-header">News<a  class="edit" href="#p_1"></a></div>
    <div class="portlet-content"></div>
             </div>
    <div class="portlet" id="p_2">
    <div class="portlet-header">Inbox<a  class="edit" href="#p_2"></a></div>
<div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing         elit</div>
     </div>
     </div>

    <div class="vsprt">
    <IMG SRC="css/images/div.png" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="65%" BORDER="0">
    </div>

    <div class="column" id="col1">
    <div class="portlet" id="p_3" >
    <div class="portlet-header">Table Widget<a  class="edit" href="#p_3"></a></div>
    <div class="portlet-content zoom" id="tb">
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="portlet" id="p_4">
     <div class="portlet-header">Announcements</div>
     <div class="portlet-content">No Latests Announcements to display</div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <img src="css/images/footer.gif" WIDTH="100%" height="10px" style="padding-            top:20px;margin-top:-200px"/>
     </div><!-- End demo -->
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Are we talking about WebLogic Portlet here?

Comment: @Harry: no the portlet I'm talking about is a simple Jquery portlet.I was wondering if it is possible to save the order of the portlets in the database so when the user come back he can see his portlets sorted in the same order?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have two options :

Saving the preferences in a database table or in Cookies. For the latter, refere to [this link](http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/cookies-with-jquery-designing-collapsible-layouts/) which explains very well how to store your user customizations in that way.

You can post some code if you want some help in coding (we don't know how you implemented your portets).

Comment: :: thank you very much for the link :) I am posting my code for your  reference

Comment: Hi Zakaria I've posted my code. I want to Store customized style information as well so that next time user logs in he sees his customized home page.Is it possible to do that?